# Retrieve path and filename of standalone MATLAB program

Tags: c, matlab

I am using MATLAB R2008b in Windows 7. 
The compiler is Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1. 
I tried to make an exe file from an m file which can retrieve its path and filename. A colleague gave me a C file (mlgetmodulefilename.c) and suggested me to use
mcc -m XYZ.m mlgetmodulefilename.c
to generate XYZ.exe

First, I got some errors regarding matlab.h. So I copied, pasted, and renamed mex.h to matlab.h.
Then, I faced the following error and warning:

> Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program 
>   Files\MATLAB\R2008b\toolbox\compiler\patch.
>   c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\mbuild~1\mlgetmodulefilename.obj
>   .text: undefined reference to '_mxCreateString'

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you.

mlgetmodulefilename.c

```
#include "matlab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "megetmodulefilename_external.h"

/*
   INPUT
   None

   OUTPUT
   None

   RETURN
   The full filename of the calling function

   SYNOPSIS

*/
#define BUFSIZE 255

mxArray * Mmegetmodulefilename(int nargout_)
{
    DWORD buflen;
    TCHAR lpFilename[BUFSIZE]=TEXT("");

    buflen = GetModuleFileName(NULL, lpFilename, BUFSIZE);

    if (buflen == 0) {
        return (mxCreateString("") );
    }
    else {
        return (mxCreateString(lpFilename) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92949-how-can-i-find-the-directory-containing-my-compiled-application) for a description on how to get the exe install path.

I haven't tested this in R2008b but it works in the latest versions.

The first option you use this directly in your m-file (I've used this a lot)

Comment: Thank you, matlabgui. I used ProgramDir=fileparts(getcurrentdir) but it only returns one level up from the folder where the exe is stored. For example, XYZ.exe is stored at "D:\ABC\XYZ.exe" but it only returns "D:\". Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use 'fileparts'. The method returns the exe folder not the exe name.